# The method getTexttActivity(Intent) is undefined for the type EditText

Tags: android, android-intent

I am getting a below compile time error.I mentioned this error at the end of that lines.

> 1. The method getTexttActivity(Intent) is undefined for the type
>      EditText
> 2. The method toStringtActivity(Intent) is undefined for the type
>      Editable

```
package com.implicitintent;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
Button read,call,msg;
EditText phone;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
read=(Button)findViewById(R.id.read);
read.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
Intent read1=new Intent();
read1.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
read1.setData(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
startActivity(read1);
}
});

phone=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.phone);
call=(Button)findViewById(R.id.call);
call.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
Intent call1=new Intent();
call1.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_CALL).setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+phone.getTexttActivity(call1)));  ---->1st error
}
});
msg=(Button)findViewById(R.id.sms);
msg.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
Intent sms=new Intent();
sms.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
sms.setData(Uri.parse("smsto:"+phone.getText().toStringtActivity(sms)));---->2nd Error
}
});
}
}
```

**activity_main.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/read"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=" View Contacts " />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/phone"
            android:layout_width="150dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/call"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=" call " />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/sms"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Send SMS" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Anybody can help me with this.thank you.

Comment: That is because those two methods are not defined in the `EditText` class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was telling you that there is no such kind of method `getTexttActivity(Intent)` in `EditText` class. Replace your code with this in `onClick` listener.

```
try {
    // set the data
    String uri = "tel:" + phone.getText().toString();
    Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse(uri));

    startActivity(callIntent);
} catch(Exception e) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your call has failed...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in your onCreate add this line (change call1 with phone in your case)

```
EditText call1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.call1);
```

then

when you want to get the text do this

```
call1.getText().toString();
```